# Testing your ActiveAdmin resources with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

I am new to Rails. I want to test my activeadmin resources as mentioned in the following link

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Testing-your-ActiveAdmin-controllers-with-RSpec

My simple test as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "activeadmin resources" do

  it "should have admin user resource" do

    ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.should have_key("AdminUser")

  end

end
```

But I am getting the error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin`
```

I tried to require activeadmin gem in spec_helper, but no use. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by changing

> require 'spec_helper'

to

> require 'rails_helper'

the error was resolved.

Comment: Please, since you solved the problem mark your answer as the correct one.